# Do two parts of a sentence have to use the same tense?

Tags: grammar, tense, tense-agreement

Do we have to use "has" in the second part of the sentence when we use it in the first part?

For example

> The central bank of China has cut its daily reference rate by 1.9 percent and made its biggest downward adjustment since 1994.

*Do I have to say* **has made** *instead of* **made**?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not. This construction implies that the entire phrase that follows *has* was completed in the past -- the central bank has done *this* and *that*. You can optionally include has if you want to emphasize the two separate actions.

---

> The central bank of China has cut its daily reference rate by 1.9 percent and made its biggest downward adjustment since 1994.

The central bank did both of these things.

> The central bank of China has cut its daily reference rate by 1.9 percent and has made its biggest downward adjustment since 1994.

The central bank did this and also that.